# Slow keyboard response on iOS Cordova App

Tags: ios, performance, cordova

I've been working on an hyrid app for Android and iOS with Cordova. I've solved the 300ms delay of the click events using [fastClick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick), but I can't find any solution to the delay my app has when an input is focused for the first time.

After the first time, the keyboard sometimes has delay, and sometimes don't. The first time the delay is always there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Im having this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes the issue. One hack might be to trigger a focus / blur on the input before the user clicks on the input themselves. However, I haven't been able to create a working code snippet, and still experience the delay...

```
// Not working: First thought
$(selection).trigger('focus');
$(selection).trigger('blur');

// Not working: Second thought
$(selection).trigger('click');
$(selection).trigger('click');
```